# Where to Get Version 1809 of Win 10

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, windows-10-upgrade

As far as I know, Version 1809 of Windows 10 was the last version that worked for my EMU1212M sound card and EmulatorX3.  Both of these are fairly expensive to replace.  I have both of them working in Version 1809 right now; unfortunately, my Windows 10 1809 has become corrupted and the Microsoft store and Windows Update no longer work.

Is there somewhere I can legally get Version 1809 of Windows 10?  I got Windows 10 for free many years ago after upgrading from XP (Paid big Bucks) to Win 7 (Paid Big Bucks) to Win 8 (Was pretty cheap) and finally Win 10 (which was free for me).

I don't see an install.ESD file in the $WINDOWS.~BT folder on my 1809 instance:
https://www.windowscentral.com/how-create-windows-10-iso-file-using-installesd-image

NOTE: I also have Emulator X3 and my 1212M working in a *test* copy of Windows 7 right now; unfortunately, I'm afraid if I upgrade that working Windows instance, I will be *forced* to select a version later than 1809 that will not support my EMU1212M.  I *do* have valid Win XP, Win 7 and Win 8 license keys but they were all used to upgrade to Windows 10 so I don't *THINK* I am technically allowed to use them for an extended length of time unless I perform a permanent downgrade.  I did *not* get a Windows 10 license key.  I got Win 10 through a free upgrade offer and it is tied to my Windows Live email account.

Comment: Reinstalling Windows 10 does not require another license.  Windows 10 activation is handled through a digital entitlement, which means you can install Windows 10 on the same machine without knowing or entering a license key.  The only requirement is that it's for the actual edition you already have installed.  Your Windows 10 license key is either your Windows 7 or Windows 8 license key (whichever was the one you used to upgrade to WIndows 10).

Comment: @Ramhound - Yes actually, I think it does.  You may unfortunately need to delete this question.  The good news is that I'm ready to go now!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find a download [here](https://tb.rg-adguard.net/public.php) for version 1809 of Windows 10.

Select the type of software to download (windows, MS Office, etc) then the version, edition and language.

[image]

Comment: @ShawnEary - The ISOs listed on the page Reddy suggested are directly from Microsoft.